# R find if overlaps in Multiple time periods

Tags: r

I'v checked my home work, saw many samples for   interval overlaps in TWO ds,  but I have single ds with  more then 3+ observations,  learned about foverlaps but it doesn't work, as it wants 2 ds A and B, in my case I have all my dates inside single df, can I do this still with foverlaps? 
on a big scale I will need to find if any overlaps for each of custID, but for now I want to make it work in simple way

```
ds <- as.Date(c('2014-9-1', '2015-5-11', '2016-11-1','2015-1-1','2015-10-1'))  # start dd
de <- as.Date(c('2015-9-30', '2016-10-31', '2030-1-1','2015-5-30','2015-12-31')) # end dd
id <- c(1,2,3,1,2)
prodid <- c('20','30','20','20','20')
custid <- c(123,123,123,4444,4444)

    df <- data.frame(custid, ds,de,id,prodid)
    df
    # find if any ovelap exists for interval between ds and de:
    ovl <- foverlaps(data.table(df), ????????, type='within')  # just sample not working
   custid         ds         de id prodid
1    123 2014-09-01 2015-09-30  1     20   \ overlap here
2    123 2015-05-11 2016-10-31  2     30   / overlap
3    123 2016-11-01 2030-01-01  3     20
4   4444 2015-01-01 2015-05-30  1     20
5   4444 2015-10-01 2015-12-31  2     20
```

Comment: overlap it with itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

ds <- as.Date(c('2014-9-1', '2015-5-11', '2016-11-1','2015-1-1','2015-10-1'))  # start dd
de <- as.Date(c('2015-9-30', '2016-10-31', '2030-1-1','2015-5-30','2015-12-31')) # end dd
id <- c(1,2,3,1,2)
prodid <- c('20','30','20','20','20')
custid <- c(123,123,123,4444,4444)

df <- data.frame(custid, ds,de,id,prodid)
df <- data.table(df)
setkey(df, ds, de)

ovl <- foverlaps(df, df, type = "within")
ovl[custid == i.custid & id != i.id]
```

What I've done is set a key, this is required for `foverlaps` to work. 
Then I filter the output, you are interested only in overlaps where the `custid == i.custid` AND when its not itself, `so id != i.id`.

```
> ovl[custid == i.custid & id != i.id]
   custid         ds         de id prodid i.custid       i.ds       i.de i.id i.prodid
1:    123 2015-05-11 2016-10-31  2     30      123 2014-09-01 2015-09-30    1       20
2:    123 2014-09-01 2015-09-30  1     20      123 2015-05-11 2016-10-31    2       30
```

this shows the overlap of interest in both combinations.

Comment: Anybody knows why I suddenly lost this result, it worked before. And I see single overlaps in input. Do you have overlap for id 1-2 for CustID=123?? I think some open source glitch....